# How to make custom Wordpress plugin aware of .po and .mo files?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, translation, poedit

I am trying to add a translation to a plugin I wrote from scratch but after experimenting a while I'm not sure how to make Wordpress aware that there's a translation available for my plugin.

I'm not sure what else to try so I thought that someone more experienced could point out things I might need to change.

**What I did so far:**

1. Added either `_e()` or `__()` to the sentences I want to be translated in my plugin files.
2. Used [Loco Translate](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) plugin to generate a `.pot` file.
3. Opened `.pot` file in Poedit, (it displayed a list of all the strings I wanted to translate) translated plugin and generated `.po` and `.mo` files from it.
4. Moved `.pot`, `.po` and `.mo` to `my-plugin/languages/`.
5. Renamed files to `my-plugin-pt.po` and `my-plugin-pt.mo`.
6. Changed Wordpress site language to translated language. Language changed everywhere else but the *plugin still renders in english.*

**Not really sure what to do next.**

I've created a method that runs `load_plugin_textdomain()` [while following these instructions from Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/) and have added it as an action to `my-plugin` `__construct()`:

*my-plugin.php*

```
public function __construct() {
  // Other filters and actions...
  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'translation_init' ) );
} // __construct

function translation_init() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin', FALSE, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language code at the end of the `.po` and `.mo` files was incorrect.
Changed from `-pt.po` to `-pt_PT.po` (did the same for `.mo` file) and it started working perfectly.

There's a [list of the available language codes for Wordpress](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/teams/) which I should have had a look before naming the files in the first place.